# Python: Static method inside private inner Enum class

Tags: python, enums, static-methods

I'm having trouble implementing an inner private enum class called: "LineCode" inside a class named Parser.

**LineCode:** Private Enum class that defines 6 types of general possible line of codes. I use Enum instantiation to send a Regex Pattern and compile it in the constructor, __init__, and then holds the Regex Matcher as a class variable.

**Parser:** Parses a programming language, irrelevant what language. Parser is using LineCode to identify the lines and proceed accordingly.

**Problem:** I can't access the enum members of __LineCode from a Static method.
I wish to have a Static method inside __LineCode, "matchLineCode(line)" that receives a string from the Parser, it then iterates over the Enum members in the following logic:

- If Match is found: Return the enum
- If no more enums left: Return None

It doesn't seem trivial, I can't access the enum members to do this.

**Attempts:** I tried iterating over the enums using:

1. __LineCode.__members__.values()
2. Parser.__lineCode.__members__.values()

Both failed since it can't find __lineCode.

**Ideally:** LineCode class must be private, and not be visible to any other class importing the Parser. Parser must use the static method that LineCode class provides to return the Enum. I am willing to accept any solution that solves this issue or one that mimics this behavior.

I omitted some of the irrelevant Parser methods to improve readability.
Code:

```
class Parser:
    class __LineCode(Enum):
        STATEMENT = ("^\s*(.*);\s*$")
        CODE_BLOCK = ("^\s*(.*)\s*\{\s*$")
        CODE_BLOCK_END = ("^\s*(.*)\s*\}\s*$")
        COMMENT_LINE = ("^\s*//\s*(.*)$")
        COMMENT_BLOCK = ("^\s*(?:/\*\*)\s*(.*)\s*$")
        COMMENT_BLOCK_END = ("^\s*(.*)\s*(?:\*/)\s*$")
        BLANK_LINE = ("^\s*$")

        def __init__(self, pattern):
            self.__matcher = re.compile(pattern)

        @property
        def matches(self, line):
            return self.__matcher.match(line)

        @property
        def lastMatch(self):
            try:
                return self.__matcher.groups(1)
            except:
                return None

        @staticmethod
        def matchLineCode(line):
            for lineType in **???**:
                if lineType.matches(line):
                    return lineType
            return None

    def __init__(self, source=None):
        self.__hasNext = False
        self.__instream = None
        if source:
            self.__instream = open(source)

    def advance(self):
        self.__hasNext = False
        while not self.__hasNext:
            line = self.__instream.readline()
            if line == "":  # If EOF
                self.__closeFile()
                return
            lineCode = self.__LineCode.matchLineCode(line)
            if lineCode is self.__LineCode.STATEMENT:
                pass
            elif lineCode is self.__LineCode.CODE_BLOCK:
                pass
            elif lineCode is self.__LineCode.CODE_BLOCK_END:
                pass
            elif lineCode is self.__LineCode.COMMENT_LINE:
                pass
            elif lineCode is self.__LineCode.COMMENT_BLOCK:
                pass
            elif lineCode is self.__LineCode.COMMENT_BLOCK:
                pass
            elif lineCode is self.__LineCode.BLANK_LINE:
                pass
            else:
                pass  # TODO Invalid file.
```

I already implemented it in Java, I want to reconstruct the same thing in Python:

```
private enum LineCode {
        STATEMENT("^(.*)" + Syntax.EOL + "\\s*$"), // statement line
        CODE_BLOCK("^(.*)" + Syntax.CODE_BLOCK + "\\s*$"), // code block open line
        CODE_BLOCK_END("^\\s*" + Syntax.CODE_BLOCK_END + "\\s*$"), // code block close line
        COMMENT_LINE("^\\s*" + Syntax.COMMENT + "(.*+)$"), // comment line
        BLANK_LINE("\\s*+$"); // blank line

        private final static int CONTENT_GROUP = 1;

        private Pattern pattern;
        private Matcher matcher;

        private LineCode(String regex) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        }

        boolean matches(String line) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            return matcher.matches();
        }

        String lastMatch() {
            try {
                return matcher.group(CONTENT_GROUP);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return matcher.group();
            }
        }
    static LineCode matchLineCode(String line) throws    UnparsableLineException {
        for (LineCode lineType : LineCode.values())
            if (lineType.matches(line)) return lineType;
        throw new UnparsableLineException(line);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the `staticmethod` to a `classmethod`, that way the first argument passed to `matchLineCode` would be the `__lineCode` class and you would be able to iterate over it

---

### Edit

I've decided to add a more detailed explanation as to why the `matchLineCode` using the `@staticmethod` decorator was unable to see the `__lineCode` class. First I recommend you read some questions posted on SO that talk about the [difference between static and class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python). The main difference is that the `classmethod` is aware of the Class where the method is defined, while the `staticmethod` is not. This does not mean that you are unable to see the `__lineCode` class from the `staticmethod`, it just means that you will have to do some more work to do so.

The way in which you organized your code, the class `__lineCode` is a class attribute of class `Parser`. In python, methods are always public, there are no private or protected class members as in Java. However, the double underscore at the beginning of a class attribute's name (or an instance's attribute's name) mean that the name will be [mangled with the class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python). This means that any function defined outside of the class `Parser` could access the `__lineCode` class as

```
Parser._Parser__lineCode
```

This means that using the `@staticmethod` decorator you could iterate over the `__lineCode` by doing

```
@staticmethod
def matchLineCode(line):
    for lineType in Parser._Parser__lineCode:
        if lineType.matches(line):
            return lineType
    return None
```

However, it is much more readable and, in my opinion, understandable to use the `@classmethod` decorator to allow the function to be aware of the `__lineCode` class.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it.
Apparently I am not familiar with the possible attributes, I will look into that.

Comment: @Ben, I'm glad my suggestion helped! I'll add a more detailed explanation as to why you were not able to see the `__lineCode` class with your `staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: @BenA:  the leading `__` for variable/method names should only rarely be used, and is primarily for helping classes and subclasses not crash into each other; the convention for "implementation detail, don't touch" is a single leading `_` for variable/method names.